# Instamojo Payment Issue

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, payment, instamojo

I could successfully get payment response from **Instamojo** API, but I couldn't find any docs that mention **instrument_type**. I wanted to know the **instrument_types** other than **CARD**. Is there any option to find it out?

Also I need to know, how can I restrict payment done via **BHIM** & **Wallet** options?

Please help me to figure this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function to extract the instrument type from your response

```
public function check(){
    try {
        $response = $this->api->paymentRequestPaymentStatus('Payment_request_id', 'Payment_id');
        dump($response);
        dump($response['payment']['instrument_type']);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        print('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: $data = json_decode($response, true);
$data['payment_request']['instrument_type']